# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable rows

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```py
for rows in chunks:
    chunk_id = rows[0,0]
```

I see error:

```
chunk_id = rows[0,0]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I don't know how to correct it. I will be grateful for help

Comment: `rows` is an int object then

Comment: The error says that `rows` is an int, so that means `chunks` is not a list of lists, it's a list of ints. - Print `chunks` before the loop and `rows` inside the loop to see it for yourself.

Comment: At least some of the time, `rows` is an integer, not something that can be indexed. It's not clear what you expect it to be (perhaps some kind of array?), but you should double check your assumptions.

Comment: In what you've posted, `rows` is undefined.  According to the error message, it's an integer.

Comment: @JainilPatel it looks as follows ```[34510, 131, 190, ..., nan, 0.66815060779908, nan],
       [34511, 131, 191, ..., nan, 0.7966411092989029, nan],
       [34512, 131, 192, ..., nan, 1.25920691469827, nan]], dtype=object), 132: array([[34585, 132, 1, ..., nan, 0.8223392095988679, nan],
       [34586, 132, 2, ..., nan, 0.5139620059992921, nan],
       [34587, 132, 3, ..., nan, 0.43686770509939904, nan],
       ...,
   ```

Comment: @JainilPatel I did it earlier and the error is the same

Comment: you are iterating dictionary the wrong way.

Comment: for chunk_id,rows in chunks.items():

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for chunk_id,rows in chunks.items():
    print ("chunk_id:",chunk_id)
```

this is how you should iterate a dictionary